# Notation for multilinear maps - is there a good reason why it is not common to write $\text{ML}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_n,W)$?

Tags: linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra, convention

Since we write $\text{L}(V,W)$ for the set of linear maps from $V$ to $W$, it seems to suggest itself to denote multilinear maps from $V_1\times\ldots\times V_k$ to $W$ by $\text{ML}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_k,W)$. Is this notation already used for something else or is there some other reason not to use it?

**Edit:** I know that it is common to use the notation $\text{L}(V_1,\ldots,V_n,W)$ for $n$-linear maps from $V_1\times\ldots\times V_n$ to $W$, but authors who use this notation (e.g. John Lee in his introduction to manifolds) constantly have to use underbraces, e.g.
\begin{equation}
\text{L}(\underbrace{U,\ldots,U}_{m\text{ copies}},\underbrace{V,\ldots,V}_{n\text{ copies}},W).
\end{equation}
I was searching for a way to avoid this, especially since this can't be used in inline equations. My idea was to write $\text{ML}(U^m\times V^n,W)$ - more generally, $\text{ML}(V_1^{n_1}\times\ldots\times V_k^{n_k},W)$.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.  I've seen it denoted by $$\operatorname{Mult}(V_1^{n_1} \times \cdots \times V_k^{n_k},W)$$

Comment: Some books use the notation $L^N(V \times \dots \times V, W)$

Comment: @D_S I realized the notation is ambiguous. That's probably why it hasn't become the standard notation.

Comment: It would be ambiguous to a computer, not to a human being.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that **the notation is ambiguous**: It's not clear whether the elements of $\text{ML}(V_1^{n_1}\times\ldots\times V_k^{n_k},W)$ are $k$-linear or $(n_1+\ldots+n_k)$-linear (consider for example bilinear maps from $\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}$).

I guess we'll have to stick to the common notation $L(V_1,\ldots,V_n,W)$. One idea would be to define
\begin{equation}
L(V_1\colon n_1,\ldots,V_k\colon n_k,W):=L(\underbrace{V_1,\ldots,V_1}_{n_1\text{ copies}},\ldots,\underbrace{V_k,\ldots,V_k}_{n_k\text{ copies}},W)
\end{equation}
to avoid having to use underbraces all the time.